# How to use Azure Cloud Explorer in VS 2019

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2019

How can I bring up the Azure Cloud Explorer in VS 2019?

I can see that it is installed when I look at "Get tools and features..." (I have the Azure Development option installed)

When I open the Server Explorer I see a message "One or more subscriptions are not supported by Server Explorer. Install Cloud Explorer from the Azure SDK to view all subscriptions."
This confuses me because I'm running VS 2019 Ultimate and I believe I have access to everything via my subscription. And as I said, "Get tools and features.." says that Cloud Explorer is already installed.

Comment: Isn't the Cloud Explorer listed under "View"->"Cloud Explorer" in your VS 2019?

Comment: Not for me. I have Solution Explorer; Team Explorer; Server Explorer; SQL Server Object Explorer; Test Explorer

Comment: Make sure the Cloud Explorer is installed using the VS Installer. It listed as optional feature of the **ASP.NET and web development** package, not the **Azure development** package. If you go to the "Individual Components" tab in the section "Cloud, database and server", you can also tick it as a single option.

Comment: I have that option ticked. Yet I cannot see it on View > Clout Explorer

Comment: @MattFitzmaurice Does `Ctrl + Q > Cloud Explorer` show something? Please try updating to the latest version of VS 2019 and check again.

Comment: Ctrl + Q > Cloud Explorer doesn't show up for me either, but I do see Cloud Explorer in my View menu